# Element#getAttribute not returning default value when attribute isn't present

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I have the following XML file:

```
<el id="el1">content</el>
```

The part of my file which defines the element above is as follows:

```
<xsd:element name="el" type="myns:el" />

<xsd:simpleType name="state">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="enabled" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="disabled" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="el">
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
    <xsd:attribute name="state" type="myns:state"
        default="enabled" />
</xsd:complexType>
```

My Java code which is supposed to obtain the default value for `state` looks like the following:

```
Element e = (Element) ns.getElementsByTagName("el").item(0);
System.out.println(e.getAttribute("state"));
```

The code above always prints an empty string if I don't set the `state` attribute in the XML file. Why is that the case? According to the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-), `getAttribute` returns

> The Attr value as a string, or the empty string if that attribute does
>   not have a specified or default value.

**My question is**: why doesn't `getAttribute` return the default value when a value is not specified?